# JavaScript Currency Coverter

Tags: javascript, html

Need help I will gradeful to you.
Hi I am doing a assignment If you can help with what am I doing wrong with this it would a big help.`

```
    <div id="box">
        <h2>Currency Converter</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><input id="fromAmount" type="text" size="15" value="0" onkeyup="conCurrency();"/></td>
            <td>
                <select id="from" onchange="conCurrency();">   
                <option value="EUR">Euro (EUR)</option>
                <option value="USD">American Dollar (USD)</option>
                <option value="GBP">British Pound (GBP)</option>
                <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
                <option value="CAD">Canadian Dollar (CAD)</option>
            </select>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td><input id="toAmount" size="15" type="text" disabled onkeyup="conCurrency();"/></td>
        <td>
            <select id="to" onchange="conCurrency();">   
            <option value="EUR">Euro (EUR)</option>
            <option value="USD">American Dollar (USD)</option>
            <option value="GBP">British Pound (GBP)</option>
            <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
            <option value="CAD" selected>Canadian Dollar (CAD)</option>
        </select>
    </td></tr>
         </table>
```

this is my Java Script I have been at since yesterday But I can't make it work.

```
var rates = {
    'EUR': 
        {'USD': 1.13, 'GBP':0.86,'YEN':127.274,'CAD':1.51}, 
    'USD': 
        {'CAD':1.33,'EUR': 0.87,'GBP':0.76,'YEN':111.96},
    'GBP':
        {'CAD':1.76,'EUR':1.16 ,'USD':1.32,'YEN':147.86}, 

    'YEN':
        {'CAD':0.0119,'EUR':0.0079 ,'USD':0.0089,'GBP':0.0068},
    'CAD':
        {'YEN':84.23,'EUR':0.66 ,'USD':0.75,'GBP':0.57}}
function conCurrency(){
    var from= document.getElementById("from").Value;
    var to= document.getElementById("to").Value;
    var fAmount =document.getElementById("fromAmount").value
    var result =0;
    if(rates[from.value] && rates[from.value][to.value]){
        result.value = fAmount * rates[from.value][to.value];
   document.getElementById("toAmount") = result;

    }
}
```

Comment: When learning javascript the first thing you should do is learn how to use the error console. Your code is throwing errors and the console is telling what and where they are. One example you set `var result = 0` and then try to assign `result.value`. `0` doesn't have a `value` property so it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I Mostly code in java(beginner) I use same logic. I didn't even know that they threw errors like that.

Comment: I know they have similar names, but JavaScript is NOT Java. They are two distinct languages for most purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues, all related to the use of the `value` property:

- It is case sensitive, so `.Value` is wrong. It should be `.value`
- When you assign the value from a `value` property to a variable, you should not take the `value` property from that variable, because then you essentially do `.value.value` which is wrong.

See comments in the corrected code:

```js
var rates = {
  'EUR': { 'USD': 1.13, 'GBP': 0.86, 'YEN': 127.274, 'CAD': 1.51 },
  'USD': { 'CAD': 1.33, 'EUR': 0.87, 'GBP': 0.76, 'YEN': 111.96 },
  'GBP': { 'CAD': 1.76, 'EUR': 1.16, 'USD': 1.32, 'YEN': 147.86 },
  'YEN': { 'CAD': 0.0119, 'EUR': 0.0079, 'USD': 0.0089, 'GBP': 0.0068 },
  'CAD': { 'YEN': 84.23, 'EUR': 0.66, 'USD': 0.75, 'GBP': 0.57 }
};

function conCurrency() {
  var from = document.getElementById("from").value; // <-- small "v"
  var to = document.getElementById("to").value;
  var fAmount = document.getElementById("fromAmount").value
  var result = 0;
  if (rates[from] && rates[from][to]) { // <--- not again .value!
    result = fAmount * rates[from][to]; // <-- variable result, not result.value
    document.getElementById("toAmount").value = result; // <--- you need .value here.
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <h2>Currency Converter</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="fromAmount" type="text" size="15" value="0" onkeyup="conCurrency();" /></td>
      <td>
        <select id="from" onchange="conCurrency();">
          <option value="EUR">Euro (EUR)</option>
          <option value="USD">American Dollar (USD)</option>
          <option value="GBP">British Pound (GBP)</option>
          <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
          <option value="CAD">Canadian Dollar (CAD)</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="toAmount" size="15" type="text" disabled onkeyup="conCurrency();" /></td>
      <td>
        <select id="to" onchange="conCurrency();">
          <option value="EUR">Euro (EUR)</option>
          <option value="USD">American Dollar (USD)</option>
          <option value="GBP">British Pound (GBP)</option>
          <option value="JPY">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
          <option value="CAD" selected>Canadian Dollar (CAD)</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: I'm just curious, is the semicolon in the onchange call valid?

Comment: It is optional. If missing, JavaScript adds it while interpreting the code.

Comment: Thank you are a life saver. Sir I can't Thanks you enough. I have spent over 6 hours. This was making go crazy.